# What are the accepted names of the different naming conventions for drives and partitions?

Tags: linux, partition

In linux for the longest time accessing a drive or partition was done with a directory-location-like address like

```
/dev/sde
```

Then in some order the `by-id` method used

```
ata-WDC-WD10EFRX-XXXXX...
```

and the UUID method used addresses that looked like

```
b8484bab-ea06-48a9-96ce-ef9b5a7def34
```

For the same of easy web search on these methods, what is the terminology used to describe each, and any other methods that may exist? I have been searching for ways to cross-correlate all the different methods buy am failing by simply not knowing the correct search terms.

Comment: Is [Persistent block device naming](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming) the term you are looking for?

Comment: I second "persistent block device naming", and for details I'd look at the `udev` rules that create the symlinks rather than search the web. While I think many distros have standardized on `by-path`, `by-id`, `by-partlabel` etc. and use the same set of `udev` rules, in principle nothing prevents distros or sysadmins from using their own set of rules with whatever conventions they find useful. You should also note that `/dev/sd*` is still the primary device node.

Answer (score 0):

The first `/dev/sde` means,

```
dev - device
sde - "sd" stands for scsi hard disk drive and "e" stands for 5th
```

The `"e"` is the 5th character counting from "a", so,

```
/dev/sda - Frist scsi hard disk drive
/dev/sdb - Second scsi hard disk drive... and so on
```

The sde or sda is called "device file" as a generic terms.
These are the same in Linux system.(using same kernel)

The second `ata-WDC-WD10EFRX-XXXXX` is just a name of hard disk drive.
Usually, the name is made up of a combination of words like this,

```
ata - Hard disk interface "Advanced Technology Attachment" 
WDC - Hard disk vendor name, assuming Western Digital
WD10EFRX - Model number
```

Regarding to UUID, please refer below URL.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier
```

I hope it will be helpful for your understanding.

Comment: I guess the OP is referring to the various paths in /dev/disk/by-... that get automatically made as symlinks by udev.

Comment: @dirkt yes exactly, if I want to ask a search engine how to correlate between a message like 'dev/sde is failing' to the actual serial number, 'name' or 'uuid', what terminology would I need to get good the right results?